# Replication CouchDB Error & Query to remote database

Tags: database, authentication, server, couchdb, replicate

I am trying to replicate a local database in couchDB to a remote db via futon. Following the doc, I don't know what to put for remote db. What is it exactly? How can I get it? Anyway I'm using.

```
 curl - POST /_replicate HTTP/1. {"source":"database","target":"http://example.org/database"}
```

Source would be the local = 127.0.0.1:5984

What would target be?

What is "database"? Is it the name of the database I made locally, demo?

[This](http://guide.couchdb.org/editions/1/en/replication.html) doc

Answer (score 1):

Database replication is what it says it is, it's creating a database on the target (optionally) and replicating the dta to that database. So you have two copies of the database now. Replication can be done as a single operation to create a copy of a database or a permanent replication can be set up so the source and target database are always in sync.
Check http://guide.couchdb.org/editions/1/en/replication.html for everything replication related.